# Handling month and sum in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a table with 3 columns: `ID, AmountCollected, Date`. I need to build a stored procedure that returns me data like this.

```
Month--CollectionSum
Jan2011|500
Feb2011|549
Mar2011|678
............
```

Jan 2011's Collection Sum should be the Sum of `AmountCollected` with dates of Jan2011 or before, Similarly Feb2011's Collection Sum should be the Sum of `AmountCollected` with dates of Feb2011 or before and so on....

Can you help me out on this? I need to build the query on SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH T AS (
    SELECT SUM(AmountCollected) AS SubTotal, YEAR([Date]) AS Y, MONTH([Date]) AS M,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY YEAR([Date]), MONTH([Date])) AS OrderID 
    FROM TestTable
    GROUP BY YEAR([Date]), MONTH([Date]) 
)
SELECT Y, M, SubTotal, 
 (SELECT SUM(T.SubTotal) FROM T WHERE OrderID <= A.OrderID) AS RunningTotal
FROM T AS A
ORDER BY Y, M
```

Here's another version without using sub-query, which should make it faster:

```
WITH T AS (
    SELECT SUM(AmountCollected) AS SubTotal, YEAR([Date]) AS Y, MONTH([Date]) AS M,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY YEAR([Date]), MONTH([Date])) AS OrderID 
    FROM TestTable
    GROUP BY YEAR([Date]), MONTH([Date]) 
)
SELECT A.Y, A.M, A.SubTotal, A.SubTotal + ISNULL(B.SubTotal, 0) AS RunningTotal
FROM T AS A
LEFT JOIN T AS B ON A.OrderID = B.OrderID + 1
ORDER BY A.Y, A.M
```

The `RunninigTotal` field adds current row's `SubTotal` with previous row's `SubTotal`. By not using another SUM to calculate the `RunningTotal`, you improve speed by avoiding each row having to add the values of all previous rows.

Comment: Glad to help. :-) You can accept the answer so this question appears as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example you can modify to fit your needs:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic460765-338-1.aspx

The key to the running total is creating a statement that joins the table to an expression that groups on the date.  But instead of saying table.date = groupeddata.date, you say table.date <= groupeddata.date in order to pick up not just the current date, but all previous dates as well.  Anyway, it will make more sense when you read the answer in the link.

Comment: Notice in that link that he does:
Inner join RunningCTE st on s.YYYY=sr.YYYY and s.YYYYMM>=sr.YYYYMM

That means the total will be cumulative over each month, but then start over for each year.  So you may need to adjust it if your totals don't start over each year.

Comment: Thanks Brandon, I had reached to the solution but even then I went to the example that you mentioned and it increased my knowledge. Thanks for helping man! May you have lots of success in your career!

Answer (score 0):

First create the regular monthwise sum table. Join two instances of this table with conditions to match each row of first table with rows from other table containing amount for this and all previous months. Finally group by the months.

```
with SumTbl (YrMon, SumAmt) as
(
   select Year(dte)*100+Month(dte), sum(amount)
   from Tbl
   group by Year(dte)*100+Month(dte)
)
select t1.YrMon, sum (t2.SumAmt) as CumAmt
from SumTb1 t1, SumTbl t2
where t2.YrMon <= t1.YrMon
group by t1.YrMon
order by t1.YrMon;
```